# How can I trigger an event right before FB.Event.Subscribe?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

Does anyone know if it's possible to trigger an event right before the FB.Event.Subscribe. I am new to Facebook API and I am trying to modify the app's webhook right before the subscribe.

````
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
    appId            : '<?= $this->app_id ?>',
    autoLogAppEvents : true,
    xfbml            : true,
    version          : 'v7.0'
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('send_to_messenger', function(e) {
        // callback for events triggered by the plugin
        console.log(e);
    });
};
</script>
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
<div class="fb-send-to-messenger"
    messenger_app_id="<?= $this->app_id ?>"
    page_id=<?= get_option('mnwoo_page_id'); ?>
    data-ref="back-in-stock-<?= $product_id ?>"
    color="<?= get_option( 'mnwoo_back_in_stock_button_color' ); ?>"
    size="<?= get_option( 'mnwoo_back_in_stock_button_size' )?:'large'; ?>"
    cta_text="<?= get_option( 'mnwoo_back_in_stock_button_text' )?:'LET_ME_KNOW'; ?>">
</div>```
````

Comment: No, that is not possible. There is no “clairvoyant” component to the whole thing, that would anticipate that one of the defined events “is about to fire soon-ish”.

Comment: _“I am trying to modify the app's webhook right before the subscribe”_ - why, what would be the point of that? And why would you do that from within _client-side_ code? You would have to expose your own admin access tokens for that.

Comment: @CBroe true, I see your point. I am trying to deploy the functionality to other sites while using the same app. Do you know the best way to approach that while only being allowed to use 1 webhook? The only other way I can think of is by using one master webhook and forwarding the responses to each client by URL. Also not 100% sure that would work. Looking forward to your suggestions!